# JWT token exp is in weird format when making an API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, jwt, momentjs

I am trying to convert the JWT exp time to a date format. The weird thing is if I use google chrome and look at local storage, I get this format: `1594663193098`

But when I use node to make an API call with the function below I get this: `21599`

Trying to convert the second one to a regular date I get 1970, unless I do something like new `Date(21599 * 73830000)` which returns approx the correct time, I know it expires in 12h or 24h, not sure.

using the token from chrome i get this result `new Date(1594663193098 * 1000) = +052502-11-12T22:04:58.000Z`

```js
const refreshToken = async () => {
  const requestBody = {
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    refresh_token
  };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  };

  const url = "https://www.externalapiurl/api/oauth2/token";

  return axios
    .post(url, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Why do I get a different exp format with node and how can i get the correct exp date from it?

Comment: First of all, you do not need to multiply timestamp by 1000. Just use `new Date(1594663193098)`

Comment: No the * is wrong. So i think i understand a bit. The time 1594663193098 from the browser is a date, the date when the JWT will expire. 21599 from the api call seems to be an amount of time until it expires. So i think i have to do current date, plus that 21599 to get the correct exp date... i think

Comment: JWT expiration times are in seconds (according to [RFC 7519 - JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-9)), but that first value you have is in milliseconds. There seems to be something wrong with the token, which might be the cause of your weird behavior.

Comment: if i take the issued at time and exp time from the localstorage token, i get -21599000 which is the expire_in value i get from the api call * 1000 (21599 * 1000). So basically chrome takes that value and converts it to a future date. How do i do that in node? I get the token, create a new Date and how do i add 21599000 to it?

Comment: What is the library you are using? It is buggy because the timestamp sgall be in seconds, not in milliseconds.

Comment: I have no idea, it's third party api. But basically the moment you get a token it tells you it expires on 6h, so i just ended up creating a timestamp and adding 6h to it

Answer (score 0):

The 21599(seconds) just tells you the token will expire in 6h, doesn't give you the actual date. So i just create a timestamp from the moment i get the token and add 6h to it.

```
timeNow = new Date()
timeNow.setSeconds(timeNow.getSeconds() + 21599);
```